# Is there a faster way to debug an ObjectARX application?

Tags: c#, vb.net, debugging, autocad, objectarx

In order to debug an ObjectARX app, an instance of Autocad is launched **each time** (!!!) from within the Visual Studio IDE on **each debug attempt**.

This yields long waste of time, waiting for Autocad to load. So my questions are:

- Is there a way to keep Autocad opened between debugging sessions? Or...
- Is it posible to write a standalone .EXE application that connects to an opened Autocad instance and use its ObjectARX objects/commands, as COM apps do with Interop objects/commands? These way would also be much faster to debug.

The last one will be slower on execution, as any out-of-process application, but instant in order to modify code and debug code logic.

EDIT: The use of [NET-RELOAD](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/net-reload-utility-for-visual-studio-download-here/td-p/3185104?nobounce=), although highly advisable, does not apply in this case because it does not allow debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting AutoCAD is really the only reliable way. Rather than  messing with acaddoc.lsp or any application settings in AutoCAD you could/should [add a command line argument](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Startup-switches-for-AutoCAD.html) in the Debug section of the Visual Studio Project settings to run a [script](http://www.cad-notes.com/learn-how-to-write-command-scripts-for-autocad-and-automate-your-plotting/) to `NETLOAD` your DLL when AutoCAD launches. [Google AutoCAD script](http://www.google.com/search?q=autocad%20script) for more resources on that if you're keen but in this case it is only one command on one line. http://www.lee-mac.com/scriptwriting.html is worth a read too. Lee Mac is always worth a read.

The text in the *Command line arguments* box should look something like

```
/b "A:\Full\Path\To\Your\Script\ScriptName.scr"
```

The contents of ScriptName.scr

```
netload "A:\Full\Path\To\Your\DLL\DLLName.dll"
```

Use the quotes because AutoCAD interprets any spaces as Enter and runs the command.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way. The only thing I do to speed it up (a bit) is use the Autoloader option of AutoCAD, and set the "Built output path" to this folder.

In this way I don't need to NETload the built Dll every time I am in debug.

Cheers,
Alain

Comment: Thanks @Alain.

For autoloading I edit (or create) the file "**[Autocad path]\Support\acaddoc.lsp**" and add a line such as:

`(command "netload" "C:\\mypath\\mydll.dll")`

Anyway, an alternative for faster debugging may be never exiting Autocad... (!!). I mean, once you launch your project for debugging and hit a breakpoint, in this moment you have an opportunity to make small modifications to your code and keep running/debugging without rstarting.

However I've had some strange exceptions, perhaps rebuilding the code at runtime is a delicate operation.

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of AutoCAD you have the option to debug using accoreconsole.exe. Well, this is a console version of AutoCAD and it will not display any graphics. But it is fast and great for other purposes.